# Can I download file from my Amazon S3 account without using S3 API?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know how to download a file using PHP. But regarding Amazon S3's API; I just want to download using my own code. API is great, but just in case I just want to create my own set of code. I know I have to set my bucket as "public".

Is this possible? - download without API; I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. AWS provided way for it.

Please refer below two documents.

1) [**Signing and Authenticating REST Requests**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html)

2) [**GET Object**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html)

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, thats no problem, but the files and bucket should be public.